# Is there any differential equation whose solution is the function itself?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

I am not sure if this is a proper question even but would like to know a robust answer, why not. Consider we have a arbitrary function  $f(t)$. The variable $t$ can be continuous or discrete. I am looking for a differential equation (DE) (or partial differential equation (PDE) with other variable) whose solution is $f(t)$ itself. In other words the solution of the DE/PDE which is satisfied by the function is the function itself.

An obvious solution to this question is the solution of zero order DE, $y(t)=f(t)$. Is there any other non-zero order DE/PDE which satisfy the above condition?

Edit: After reading the comment of @anomaly I think the question can be written as for what $L$ we have $L(f)=f$.

Comment: $y' = f'$, etc. Or are you looking for a linear (or more complicated) differential operator $L$ with $L(f) = f$?

Comment: The zero function satisfies any homogeneous differential equation, so it satisfies your needs if $y = f$ is a solution of $\text{something in terms of }y\text{ and it's derivatives} = f(t)$ is what you seek.

Comment: I wouldn't call $y(t)=f(t)$ a differential equation, since there are no differentials or derivatives involved. There are plenty of differential equations a function may satisfy. Introductory courses on ordinary and partial differential equations customarily begin with a section on how to form differential equations satisfied by various functions. As an example, you can differentiate $y(t)=t$ to get $y'(t)=1,0=y''(t)=y'''(t)=...$

Comment: @anomaly Any equation where L(f)=f;

Comment: Very interesting question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set

$$L(y)=y$$ solve for $y$. Then automatically $y=f(t)$ will solve the differential equation.

I will give a simple example $y'=y \implies y(x) = c\exp(x)$. Hence, $y'=c\exp(x)$ is a differential equation of the type that you were looking for.

---

**Construction of infinitely many differential equations**: You can construct infinitely many other examples by starting from $y=g(t)$. Then evaluate some nonlinear $F$ with $F(y,y',...,y^{(n)})$ and set the result of $F$ as your $f(t)$.

Comment: Thank you for the question :). Learned something new today :D. Construction of such differential equations is trivial as well as checking if a given differential equation is of this type. You can simply test $y=f(t)$ and see if it solves the differential equation.

Comment: Is it possible to define L for the Wiener filter. Can it be a separate question?

Comment: You should post it as a separate question.