# Is Wiener filter a solution of some differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question

The motivation for this question is related to the link: [Is there any differential equation whose solution is the function itself?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3145674/is-there-any-differential-equation-whose-solution-is-the-function-itself) The question in the link arises as I was looking for an answer in the https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/55931/is-match-filter-a-solution-of-some-differential-equation . The answer obtained in the dsp site leads me to ask the question in this math site.

Now the question can we have a $L$ whose solution is Wiener filter. By Wiener filter I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_filter

Comment: The article Wiener filter is impossible to understand. Did you mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution then can you state your question precisely using their notations

Comment: @reuns Yes it is same, only additional condition is h is known and equal to 1.  So Wiener filter is to remove the effect of the additive Gaussian noise alone.